# google.protobuf installed, but module not found

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, osx-yosemite

I have installed protobuf but when I run my script that uses pb.py it complains:

```
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
    ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

However when I run protoc --version I see libprotoc 2.6.1
The previous posts say to see if protobuf is within the path of python, I can't find the protobuf path though.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm running Yosemite.

Comment: This question looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196648/how-can-i-use-protocol-buffers-for-python-on-windows

Comment: libprotoc and python protobuf are two separate packages installed in completely different ways. Are you sure you installed both of them, or did you only install protoc?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful how the quotes are rendered, they should be BACKquotes:

```
export PROTOC_PATH=`which protoc`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had that exact problem yesterday. Basically you have protoc already, you just need to let Python see it. Here's how to do it:
In your terminal: `export PROTOC_PATH = 'which protoc'` and then `echo $PROTOC_PATH` and then add PROTOC_PATH to your .bash_profile.

Hope that helps!