# Modules are installed using pip on OSX but not found when importing

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, import, module

I successfully install different modules using pip and they are shown in the

```
pip list
```

such as:

```
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
requests (2.10.0)
Scrapy (1.1.0)
```

#### From Terminal

However, whenever I try to import it

`import beautifulsoup4` / `import bs4` or `import Scrapy` or `import requests`

the following error is shown:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

*Update:* if I launch python when I am at the correct site-packages directory

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> import scrapy
```

Then it works. This would solve the issue if writing directly on the Terminal. However, I have no clue about how to make it work inside a file.py, which will be the normal use.

As far as I know, I only have Python2.7 installed.

#### From file.py

If I have a file.py saved in some local folder. This contains, for instance

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

when I try

```
python file.py
```

I get the same error.

## Approach

Same happens with any other module from the list.
I would think pip is installing them in a directory that Python is not reading, but as per what I read, it is the correct one.

They are all installed here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Output requested by Padraic Cunningham:

```
$ which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Output requested by leovp:

```
$ pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

#### Threads already checked

I have checked the following threads, but unfortunately they did not help me to solve the issue:

- [installing pyside using PIP - nmake not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899996/installing-pyside-using-pip-nmake-not-found)
- [PIp installs but module is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569846/pip-installs-but-module-is-not-found) ==> might have provided the right answer, but the links given do not work anymore
- [google.protobuf installed, but module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802358/google-protobuf-installed-but-module-not-found)
- [Python pip install module is not found. How to link python to pip location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052206/python-pip-install-module-is-not-found-how-to-link-python-to-pip-location)

Any ideas of what the problem is?

Comment: You are definitely not using the interpreter that pip is installing for, add the output of `which -a pip` and `which -a python`

Comment: What does `pip -V` show? Is there a chance that you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added the output.

Comment: OK, now start a shell with `/usr/local/bin/python` and try importing.

Comment: @leovp I added also the output you requested

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, this is what I get: `$ cd /usr/local/bin/python` and 
`-bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/python: Not a directory`
If I just go one level above, it is OK, and doing `ls` shows actually inside the list a `python` directory

Comment: @JoanMM, I meant just type `/usr/local/bin/python` and hit enter. Your system/default python is `/usr/bin/python`, pip is installing for `/usr/local/bin/python` so that is why you cannot seem to import anything you install,  when you just type `python` then the `/usr/bin/python` interpreter is started .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, that works. Should I add this somehow in my python.py file?

Comment: If you want python to start your `/usr/local/bin/python` interpreter the simplest way would be to export the path in your .bashrc file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, wouldn't it make more sense that pip just installs all modules for `/usr/bin/python`? Could that be done?

Anyhow, if the simplest way is the one you meant, could you explain how to export the path in my .bashrc file?

Comment: Simplest solution for that is to download get-pip.py and install it with /usr/bin/python get-pip.py  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your problem maybe caused due to various reason, I have listed down a few of them here :

- This is possibly because of what ever is stated here : [Pip installs but module is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569846/pip-installs-but-module-is-not-found). Have updated the answer with newer link.

The link you were looking for : https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode

- It may also happen if you have **two versions of python installed**. If the `pip` that you are accessing is of one version & the python interpreter used is another.

So just see to that you are using the same version of python to install and use the package.

**You may fix this using alias,**

First, set up a shell alias:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Then, type that at a prompt, or put it in your `~/.bashrc` so that whenever you open python from the terminal the correct version opens.

- If both of the above methods don't work for you then check this :

[ImportError No module named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587457/importerror-no-module-named-python)

Comment: You were right Ani Menon, there are two versions of python installed. I explained in an answer how I proceeded to solve the problem.

Comment: Good you may also fix it using aliases. If both your python versions are assigned different aliases it will be easy to use both as required. (I don't know why someone gave a down-vote to the answer!)

Comment: Interesting, could you expand a bit more about the aliases?

Comment: Using `alias` command; answer edited. Similarly, you may alias `pip` as well.

Comment: Do a `brew reinstall python2`. It might complain it can't delete some files. If that's the case, make sure all files in your `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` are owned by you (i.e. `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages ; sudo chown -R <YOURLOGIN> *`). Then retry `brew reinstall python2` and `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` and finally use pip to install your library. `pip install X`.

Answer (score 26):

Here the answer that worked, which is basically what has been explained in the comments of the question. However, I thought it would be useful to have it explained as a clear and well structured answer.

As highlighted, the problem was that I was not using the interpreter that pip was installing for.
The command `which` shows where pip was installing the modules:

```
$ which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

and where the different python versions were located:

```
$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

That is, my system/default python was

```
/usr/bin/python
```

while pip was installing for

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Therefore, I could not import anything I installed when I just typed `python`, because the `/usr/bin/python` interpreter was the one started.

### Solution

**Install pip again** specifying the destination of the modules that will be installed. This must be the destination for the system/default python.

This has been done in two steps:

1. Downloding `get-pip.py` from [bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). (You may need to use the deprecated one for Python 2: [bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py))
2. Installing it with the following command

   `sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py`

Note that without the `sudo` I got an error and was not able to install pip.

Comment: Hi, I was facing a similar same issue. In my case, in Mac OS High Sierra, `which -a pip` yields `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `which -a python` yields `/usr/bin/python`.  I tried the same procedure, but I am failing.  I downloaded get-pip.py into my desktop and ran `sudo /usr/bin/python ~/Desktop/get-pip.py`. The procedure runs fine, but when I run `which -a pip`, I still only get `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, it also was located in `/usr/local/bin/pip` before and after install. So you could say nothing changed, but in fact, something changed, because now it's working. `sudo` was not required for me. I'm running Mojave.

Answer (score 18):

I have just fixed a similar issue.

To give some background, I install `pip` with `homebrew` by executing `brew install python`. One drawback by executing this command, it will install both python2 and python3(maybe not a disadvantage in some case), then

`pip install scrapy`

but when I try to `import scrapy`, it complained `ImportError: No module named scrapy`.

---

**My Solution:**
run `brew doctor`, it should report you a link is broken, it asks you to run `brew link python`, you might encounter some errors, but follow the prompt suggestion to move forward, after successfully executing `brew link python`, everything should work now.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this problem by running:

```
$ brew doctor
```

and got the following:

> Consider setting your PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` occurs before `/usr/bin`.
>
> Here is a one-liner:

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Once I ran the one-liner, I was able to access the installed package from `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this in case it helps anyone else out. For me the issue was I was running Anaconda and pip3 was installing to a different directory than Anaconda was linked with. To fix this run `conda deactivate`. You can reactivate later with `conda activate`

Comment: For me it was just pip in general, it would install but wasn't available to import. Needed to use `pip3 install <module name>` instead of `pip install <module name>` and then it becomes available to Python 3. This on Mac where either Python 2 is available only or both Python 2 and Python 3 are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Run `brew doctor`in the terminal
it should give you a warning that says:

```
Warning: The following directories do not exist:
/usr/local/sbin

You should create these directories and change their ownership to your account.
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin
```

type `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin` in the terminal and hit enter
then type `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin`
then run python and try importing your module again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the VSCode interpreter to ~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that `pip3.11`installs new modules to `/usr/local/lib/python3.11`(or whatever your python version is) which is not a path the python binary considers when looking for modules.

As a workaround you can specify the modules path in the variable `PYTHONPATH` like

```
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/" python3.11 my_script.py
```

Alternatively one can specify a directory where pip should new modules to with the `-t`option.

```
# print module paths which are considered by python
python3.11
Python 3.11.3 (main, Apr  8 2023, 04:18:45) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
```

```
# install new module to one of the above listed directories
pip3.11 install my_module -t /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

For some specific cases such as crypto module in python, after I install it in Pycharm, I will have to locate to the "crypto" module path and then change the directory name to "Crypto".

Comment: The usage of crypto/pycrypto is [highly](https://blog.sqreen.com/stop-using-pycrypto-use-pycryptodome/) [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/11395264) for security reasons.