# Pip install is not working with python but working with python2

Tags: python, macos, pip, macos-high-sierra

I have an issue with Python on my Mac with High Sierra. 
After running `pip install pysal`, I have a successful installation. However, the module is not found when I run in `python`:

```
> import pysal 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named pysal
```

I do not face such errors when running the same command in `python2`. However, most of my python scripts call the interpreter at the beginning of the file with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, so I would prefer not having to rely on python2 (I don't know how to do it either).

I figured out that this is python's executable is not on the same location where pip installs the modules:

```
macbook-pro-3:~ ME$   which -a python
/usr/bin/python 
macbook-pro-3:~ ME$   which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

I tried to follow the solution proposed by @J0ANMM in [Modules are installed using pip on OSX but not found when importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341614/modules-are-installed-using-pip-on-osx-but-not-found-when-importing/37344381#comment91321331_37344381) . It recommeds downloading the script get-pip.py and executing it with `sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py`. I tried, but it did not change anything (the previous `which` commands still yield the same thing).

How do I manage to make  `pip` work with my version of python?

Comment: install pip3, pip3 is for python3. Then install packages in python3 using pip3

Comment: I don't have python 3

Comment: do you have two python2 versions, one named python and the other python2?

Comment: The easiest thing you can do is to install anaconda or miniconda. https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: yes i 2nd @KhalilAlHooti comment. you should be running in virtual environments if you have more than one version of python on your Mac.