# How do I confirm that pip install is installing to the correct python version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm running Python on a Mac.

I have the following code:

```
import shelve, pyperclip, sys

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')

#Save clipboard content
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    #List keywords and load content
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```

However when I run the file I get the below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mcb.py", line 7, in 
    import shelve, pyperclip, sys
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

I've already installed pyperclip with pip install.

When I googled this issue one thing that came up is having multiple versions of python installed and having pip install the module to a different version than the python version that is being used when the file is run. [Modules are installed using pip on OSX but not found when importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341614/modules-are-installed-using-pip-on-osx-but-not-found-when-importing/37342150#37342150)

I'm wondering how can I check to see where pip install is installing the module and more importantly how can I check to see which python version I'm using.

When I run `which -a pip` I get:
 /Users/stephenlang/anaconda/bin/pip

When I run `which -a python`I get:
/Users/stephenlang/anaconda/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Is there a way to easily align pip install to the correct python version?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install`?

Comment: I get this:
python -m pip install pyperclip
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /Users/stephenlang/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.8.0)

But the error persists when running the file.

Comment: Does `python -c "import pyperclip"` work?

Comment: No output from that, and the file still will not run.

Comment: Read this: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/