# MacOS - Python says module not found, but it's already installed

Tags: python, macos, terminal, module

I am trying to run a Python script locally using `python3`. This script requires `proxymanager`.

```
Requirement already satisfied: proxymanager in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0.6)
```

However, when I run the script, I get the following message:

```
  File "/Users/xxx/Folder/script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from proxymanager import ProxyManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proxymanager'
```

```
Python 3.9.0
```

I believe Python is installed here:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9`

Any help would be appreciated, still new to this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same python distribution for checking the packages and invoking the script?

Comment: `pip --version` tells you which `python` the `pip` is attached to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modules are installed using pip on OSX but not found when importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341614/modules-are-installed-using-pip-on-osx-but-not-found-when-importing)

Comment: Have you tried `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 /Users/xxx/Folder/script.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it and reinstalling again, maybe using

`pip uninstall proxymanager`

Does it work? Otherwise, are you using an IDE like PyCharm?

Comment: It does remove it, but when I reinstall with `pip3 install ProxyManager`, the script still won't run. I am using Terminal for the install.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that you are using `pip` for a different Python distribution. Here are the steps to make sure everything goes as planned.

1. Make sure you run the distribution you need. Type `which python3` into your terminal and see which Python gets run. Is it the one you expected? If not, consider [using a symlink](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf) or maybe stick to the one that actually gets run.
2. You can launch `pip` for the interpreter you need by using [option -m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610082/3694363):

   ```sh
   python3 -m pip install proxymanager
   ```
3. Launch your script again and see if everything goes as planned.

Consider also using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to avoid this type of confusion in the future.

Comment: ```% which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3```

It is the one I expected, Python3. So, I am using Terminal for all these installs, should I be using something else?

Comment: That's correct, just use the terminal, that's all you need really. The command `python3 -m pip install proxymanager` will install your library in the correct place.

Comment: ```python3 -m pip install proxymanager
Requirement already satisfied: proxymanager in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0.6)``` and then

```python3 -m pip uninstall proxymanagger
WARNING: Skipping proxymanagger as it is not installed.```

Comment: Oh wow, this is something weird. Unfortunately I don't know the explanation for this behavior, I can only offer a couple of workarounds. (1) Try deleting the folder for proxymanager inside `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages` manually and installing it again (2) Try using a virtual environment, they isolate the installed libraries really well and maybe it'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking at virtual environments. What the problem maybe here is that your python installation is looking in the wrong place for `proxymanager`.

A virtual environment is a confined environment for a given project, so if you only needed certain packages for one project then you could just deal with this environment and install them to that environment. It makes developemnt and deploying projects a lot easier.

Try this, create a new folder and open a terminal window in this folder.
Run the following commands. It uses the package [Venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which comes with Python.

Create the environment in a folder `MyProj`

```
MyProj>> python -m venv MyEnv
```

Activate the environment

```
MyProj>> cd MyEnv/Scripts
Scripts>> ./activate
```

You will know it is activated as your command prompt will now have the name of the environment in front of it. Now install your package.

```
(MyEnv)MyProj>> pip install proxy-manager
```

Ensure that it is installed in your Environment.

```
MyProj>> cd MyEnv/Lib/site-packages
site-packages>> ls 
pip
pip-19.2.3.dist-info
pkg_resources
proxymanager    ***** HERE IT IS *****
proxy_manager-0.0.6-py3.7.egg-info
setuptools
setuptools-41.2.0.dist-info
tests
__pycache__
easy_install.py
```

Now try to run your script and it should use the virtual environment you have created.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did `pip3 list` to check what modules were currently installed.

I saw that `ProxyManager` was installed but it wasn't the correct module. I typed `pip3 uninstall ProxyManager`. Then I typed `pip3 install proxy-manager`. The script worked perfect after this change.

I'm unsure what was causing the error, but looks like it needed `proxy-manager` and not `ProxyManager`.

Log:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proxymanager'
```

Now it works just fine. I still don't understand much of what's happening, but it looks like there's two packages with the similar name? It doesn't help that Terminals output is that `ProxyManager` is missing, when it was installed the entire time. The correct output should have been `Proxy-Manager` is missing?

Either way, thanks to everyone that has helped.