# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip' in Mu-Editor (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, mu

I'm getting this error when I try to import pyperclip in Mu-Editor but in Idle it imports just fine.  I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341614/modules-are-installed-using-pip-on-osx-but-not-found-when-importing/37342150#37342150) .  One of the solutions is to download get-pip.py from [here](http://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) but I'm at a loss as to how I download it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's actually the same thread I linked in the original post, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't see the links

Comment: To install pip, go [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and download the get-pip.py file. Then use the following command in the command prompt: `python get-pip.py`

Comment: That's the part I'm confused about. When I go to that link it just opens a webpage with a bunch of code. Is that what I'm supposed to see? If so, how exactly do I download the get-pip.py file? Sorry, I'm completely new to this 

Comment: It should show a dialogue box to download pip. I'm on a windows machine, so I'm not sure if this is the same on mac

Comment: Well good news is I was able to download get-pip.py .  Had to copy the entire code and save it in the right directory.  Bad news is Mu-Editor still errors out.  I also have a PC which has the same issue.

Comment: Huh, that's strange. Please update your question, with the error that comes up

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'         
                                                                                             I'm wondering if it even matters though because it only errors out in Mu-Editor but Idle is fine.  I haven't actually tried to run any programs through Python so I don't know if the error in Mu-Editor even matters, does it?

Comment: How did you install pyperclip, pip or pip3?

Comment: Both pip and pip 3

Comment: I think it must just be a bug with mu editor, if everything works fine in IDLE

Comment: Yeah I figured. I'm going to ignore it for now since I don't think it affects any programs I create. Thanks so much for being so responsive! I really appreciate it!