# Why is package pandas in Juyter unknown?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

I‘ve installed Jupyter with `brew install jupyterlab` on my M1 Mac. I started `jupyter lab` and created a new notebook. As kernel I‘ve chosen the only available IPython3. I‘ve then tried to import pandas and got unknown module. Afterwards I tried `!pip install pandas` and got that’s already installed.

Executing `python3 —version` outputs `3.11.3` while `print(sys.version);` gives `3.12.2`.

I have no idea what’s the reason and how to solve that issue.

BR

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37341614/6394617)?

Comment: Gerrit, in 2019 the magic install command was added. You should be using `%pip install pandas` inside a running notebook to make sure that things are installed to where the kernel associated with your running `.ipynb` file. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). As you've found, using the exclamation point in association with the will install things but not necessarily to the correct location. Use this as a gauge for evaluating how current advice is that you find.