# How do I add a 'google' module for protocol buffers in Python in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: python, visual-studio, protocol-buffers

I'm following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial .

I've managed to create the `addressbook_pb2.py` from the proto file. I added `addressbook_pb2.py` to my project, and when I do `import addressbook_pb2` the .py file pops up as I type the name, so I know the program recognizes it.

When I try to run the program, which consists of only the line `import addressbook_pb2`, I receive the error `No module named 'google'`. I am extremely new to Python, how would I go about fixing this error? I am running Python 3.4 in Visual Studio 2013

The error is caused at each `importing google.protobuf` line in my 'addressbook_pb2.py' file

```
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: addressbook.proto
import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
```

Comment: What does the adderssbook_pb2.py file look like on the inside?  I suspect you may need to tweak either your import or your reference to the module.

Comment: I added the beginning of the file. I receive the error almost immediately in this file too.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308812/no-module-named-google-protobuf) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196648/how-can-i-use-protocol-buffers-for-python-on-windows).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the command line to install it. My problems ended up being a combination of having multiple Pythons installed (2.7 and 3.4) and just not being familiar with pip, both of which are explained in those posts

Comment: Good to hear you solved the issue. I'll post it in an answer for other that read this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is often caused by having multiple Pythons installed. Solutions to this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196648/how-can-i-use-protocol-buffers-for-python-on-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308812/no-module-named-google-protobuf).